# Chamberlain Internet Gateway connected to MyQ Garage Opener, but doesn't appear in app

Tags: garage, garage-door-opener

My Liftmaster Garage Door Motor has the MyQ logo on it. I wanted to control it from my iPhone and found that I needed to buy a Chamberlain or Liftmaster Internet Gateway to do that.

I bought the gateway (Chamberlain brand) and wired it to my router and power.

I created an account on their website, https://www.mychamberlain.com

I was able to add the Internet Gateway.

I clicked Add Device -> Garage Door -> non-WiFi. It said to press the Learn button. I did so. After ~5 seconds the lights on my motor flashed. Seemed promising except one problem - my iPhone said it was still waiting to hear from the device.

A few minutes later my iPhone had a popup saying that waiting for the device had timed out. As far as I can tell, the device isn't associated with my account at all. I looked through the help section and found this page on what the LED lights mean:
http://www.chamberlain.com/CatalogResourcesV3/en-us/ccv3/support/myq/2_2/en/mobile/advanced/Content/CIGBU/CIGBULEDs.htm

I currently have a solid green light and a solid blue light. The solid green means it has an internet connection and IP address and everything. The solid blue means it has been programmed with at least one device.

So that suggests to me that the Internet Gateway was completely set up properly... just for some reason the Garage isn't showing up either on the app, or online.

So... what do I do now? How do I go about actually getting the device to show up? Should I just repeat the steps for programming? Is there some way to undo whatever it is that I've already done?

If it's important, the Internet Gateway is sitting right next to my Router, which is located on the main floor directly above my garage. My iPhone's wifi signal is fine in the garage... although I suppose that might be irrelevant since the gateway probably communicated with the motor on some completely different frequency...

(I already tried calling tech support, but they're closed right now... they open in 13 hours... but maybe someone on this website knows the answer... and no matter what, in the future the answer can be online and people won't have to call tech support at all...)

Comment: Does it require port-forwarding?

Comment: Great question... I have no idea. The little direction booklet doesn't mention that at all. Any idea how I could find out... Which port would I even forward from/to?

Comment: No idea, but I would call the company here.

Comment: Their tech support should be of assistance, if they're any better than Micro$oft.

Answer (score 1):

I called up tech support this morning.

They told me that if the gateway said it was programmed (as indicated by a steady blue light), but the device wasn't appearing, it meant that I needed to reset the gateway.

**Resetting the Gateway**

The process for resetting the gateway is you disconnect it from power, then press the recessed button located on the long side above the logo sticker - I used a bent paperclip to do this. While still pressing the button, connect it to power.

Once you see the "yellow" (looked orange to me) light come on, you can release the button.

The device should now be reset. The green light will flash indicating that it's trying to get an internet connection. Eventually it should become solid (within ~20 seconds), indicating that it has its connection.

**Adding the Device**

Login to your account on your computer or phone again and tell it to add the device. Press the learn button on the motor and within ~5 seconds the main lightbulbs on the motor (not the smaller LEDs) should flash, indicating that the gateway has successfully been connected.

Check your account again and the device should now appear properly.

Hope this helps other people.